# Font Awesome not showing on my localhost

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I am using font awesome on webpage and non of the following is working on my local system

```
<a href="#header" class="fa fa-angle-down"></a>
<a href="#header" class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-down" style="font-size:24px"></a>
```

Same code works on fiddle but not the local host

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">`

http://jsfiddle.net/ZF7x4/33/

http://fontawesome.io/icon/arrow-circle-o-down/

I am not sure why it is not working i tried few thing but it is not working

**UPDATE**:

While trouble shooting further i noticed it only shows following css in localhost

```
.fa {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-feature-settings: normal;
    font-kerning: auto;
    font-language-override: normal;
    font-size: inherit;
    font-size-adjust: none;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-synthesis: weight style;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1;
    text-rendering: auto;
}
.fa {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1;
}
```

And rest of which is visible on fiddle is not showing in localhost. Not sure why while i am using same cdn link

```
.fa-angle-down::before {
    content: "";
}
.fa-angle-down::before {
    content: "";
}
```

UPDATE 2:

Issue seems to be only with `anchor` when i use same for `<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>` it works why?

Comment: your jsfiddle seems to be working perfectly fine; what's the problem?

Comment: try having a look at your browser console/ network tab in Developer Tools/ mode. Does the `.min.css` load properly?

Comment: That is working properly , try to check in your console is there any errors

Comment: @Mr_panda, Yes it is only the `.fa {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-feature-settings: normal;
  font-kerning: auto;
  font-language-override: normal;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-size-adjust: none;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-synthesis: weight style;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  text-rendering: auto;
}`

Comment: can you please share your .html file ?

Answer (score 1):

Check whether you are declaring for UTF-8 in your document?

`<meta charset="UTF-8">`

or

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

You can also use the below link,

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Also you can try this in your css,

```
 @font-face {
      font-family: 'FontAwesome';
      src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot');
    }
```

Comment: I have `<meta charset="UTF-8">` included regarding `@font-face {
      font-family: 'FontAwesome';
      src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot');
    }` shouldn't this come from the `font-awesome.min.css`

Comment: Did you try running it in a private window??  As there may be some cache issues in normal..

Answer (score 1):

For my case,

```
<i class="fas fa-google"></i>
```

was not working, I found out that to make it work I, need to use it as

```
<i class="fab fa-google"></i>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make use of the console on your browser inspect, option from there you will be able to see which file are not found, it might be the fonts,ttf file, download that file from github place it on the directory that it was try to load it from that should work

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
   </head>
    <body>


        <a href="#header" class="fa fa-angle-down" style="font-size:24px"></a>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <a href="#header" class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-down" style="font-size:24px"></a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

i also faced the same problem. my css cdns were loading good but script cdns were not loading. what you do is when ever you type your localhost address in url  box of browser do following:

```
http://localhost:<port>/
```

this worked for me. Hope that it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because since font awesome 5 and up you you also need to include some other files.

2 solutions

1- use the web CDM

2- add all other folders to the localhost directory and it will work instantly

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I got that working by simply changing the address in
`href` attribute of my html file.

Before I gave the location of css file w.r.t to my current html file(`index.html`) as my `index.html` and fontawesome folder were in same folder(Hospital Inventory).

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="\fontawesome\css\all.css">`

then I gave it w.r.t to the `localhost` and it worked...

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="\Hospital inventory\fontawesome\css\all.css">`